# jQuery: Trouble with multiple current overstates

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to customize my jQuery script to recognize different "current" states when I click on 1 of 3 different tabs. Currently the code only allows one "current" state to be recognized so when I click on a different tab the same overstate for the button is shown. I have sifted through my code for many hours and I now differ to your expertise for help.

**Possible solution?:**
Add in some sort of ID listener that recognizes what current state to display as the overstate.

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#"><img src="textSpacer.png" width="87" height="20"></a>
  <ul>
    <img src="subContentSearch.gif">
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="textSpacer.png" width="84" height="20"></a>
    <ul>
    <img src="subContentNewsSignUp.gif">
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="textSpacer.png" width="100" height="20"></a>
    <ul>
    <img src="subContentMyVictory.gif">
    </ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery.Clickme.js:**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.clickMe = function(op_user) {

    var menuName = this,                
        op = $.extend( cm.op_default , op_user);

    $(menuName).find("li:has(ul)").addClass("arrow");
    // move content to inicial margin
    $(op.moveIt).css({ marginTop: op.moveItMargin });

    //  anchor inside menu active the code
    $(menuName).find("a").click(function() {

        var ulsVisible = $(menuName).find("ul").is(":visible");
        var testUl = $(this).next("ul").is(":visible");

        // hide and remove op.activeMenu class from visible list inside the menu 
        if (ulsVisible) {
            // know if the anchor that active the function is visible
            if(testUl) {                    
                $(menuName).find("li").removeClass(op.activeMenu);
                moveContent(); 
                $(this).next("ul").animate(op.aniHide, op.speed);           
            } else {
                $(menuName).find("li").removeClass(op.activeMenu);                      
                $(menuName).find("ul").animate(op.aniHide, op.speed);
                $(this).parent("li").addClass(op.activeMenu);
                 moveContent();
                $(this).next("ul").animate(op.aniShow, op.speed );
            }
        } else {
            $(this).parent("li").addClass(op.activeMenu);
            moveContent();
            $(this).next("ul").animate( op.aniShow, op.speed);          
        }
    });

    // Move content 
    function moveContent() {

        var ulHeight = $("."+op.activeMenu +" ul").height() ;
        var moveMargin = parseFloat($(op.moveIt).css("margin-top"));
        var dif = ulHeight + op.moveItMargin - moveMargin;                  

        if (ulHeight == moveMargin) {

        } else if (ulHeight < moveMargin) {
            $(op.moveIt).animate({marginTop: "+=" + dif}, op.speed);

        } else if (ulHeight > moveMargin){
            $(op.moveIt).animate({marginTop: "+=" + dif}, op.speed);            

        }                                           
    }

};

var cm = $.fn.clickMe;
cm.op = {};
cm.op_default = {
    activeMenu: "current",
    moveIt: ".content",
    moveItMargin : 0,
    aniShow: { opacity: "show", height: "show"},
    aniHide: { opacity: "hide", height: "hide"},
    speed: "fast"
};
```

})(jQuery);

**CSS Snippet being Used:**
.current {background-color: #D1EFEF;}
.current a {color: #FFF; background-image:url("siteSearch_down.gif");}
.current a:hover {color: #000;}

I am sincerely thankful for your time and help.

Comment: you're going to have a hard time getting people to download and view the contents of a zip.  why dont you pick the pieces you think are most relevant and put it in the post?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jon, I made the edits to my question per your request. I would prefer to just post the url to the working example. Is that safe to do?

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark, but maybe doing something like setting states in outer scope helps you..

`var fnc, state = 'state1';
fnc = function () {
  if (state === 'state1') {
    // do something 
    // update the state
    state = 'state2';
  }
  // ... etc
};`

Comment: Zack, now that I added the full jQuery being used. Do you have a different suggestion. Towards the bottom of the jQuery code you will see: activeMenu: "current",. This is being called in the CSS.